# error: non-scalar cast: `core::option::Option<i32>` as `usize`

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust. My code is given below:

```
use std::*;

fn DFS(A: i32, grid: &mut [[i32; 500]; 500], visited: &mut [i32; 500]) -> (usize, usize) {
    let mut s = Vec::new();
    s.push(A);
    visited[A as usize] = 1;
    let mut flag;
    let mut max_height = 0;
    let mut ans_vertex: usize = A as usize;
    let mut x;

    'outer: while let Some(top) = s.pop() {
        s.push(top);
        x = top as usize;

        flag = 0;
        'inner: for i in 1..500 {
            if visited[grid[x][i] as usize] == 0 && grid[x][i] != 0 {
                flag = 1;
                s.push(grid[x][i]);
                visited[grid[x][i] as usize] = 1;
                break 'outer;
            }
        }
        if s.len() > max_height {
            max_height = s.len();
            ans_vertex = s.pop() as usize;
        }
        if flag != 0 {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
    println!("{}, {}", ans_vertex, max_height);
    return (ans_vertex, max_height);
}

fn fc(grid: &mut [[i32; 500]; 500]) {
    for i in 1..500 {
        for j in 1..500 {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    grid[1][2] = 1;
    grid[2][1] = 1;
    grid[2][3] = 1;
    grid[3][2] = 1;
    grid[3][4] = 1;
    grid[4][3] = 1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut visited: [i32; 500] = [0; 500];
    let mut grid: [[i32; 500]; 500] = [[0; 500]; 500];

    fc(&mut grid);
    let B = DFS(1, &mut grid, &mut visited);
    println!("{}", B.0);
}
```

I already tried changing `usize` to `u32` and other types, but I'm not getting any results. When I run `rustc newdia.rs`, it shows:

```
  newdia.rs:26:17: 26:33 error: non-scalar cast: `core::option::Option<i32>` as `usize`
  newdia.rs:26          ans_vertex = s.pop() as usize;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vec::pop()` returns an `Option<T>` because if the Vec is empty, there's no value present to pop. If you're sure your Vec contains atleast 1 value before you call `Vec::pop()`, you can use `Option::unwrap()`, which will convert your `Option<i32>` to `i32` (and panic if `Vec::pop` returned `None` because the Vec was empty).

```
ans_vertex = s.pop().unwrap() as usize;
```

You can also choose to handle the cases differently using `match` or `if let`:

```
if let Some(popped) = s.pop() {
    // Successfully popped `popped`. `popped` here is an i32.
} else {
    // `s` was empty.
}
```